# Is there an alternative to JQuery`s event delegation?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to be able to assign a function to keypress of elements that don't exist when the DOM loads. In jQuery the code I had is like this

```
$(document).on('keypress', '.sc-chat-window .sc-user-input--text, #waste-form input,#address,.waste-wise-container .form-control,.widget-box .form-control,#aria-main-search-form-field,#footer-search-field,#aria-feedback-form-field', function(e) {
    updateLastTypedTime();
});
```

It worked fine, but the problem is I can't use jQuery anymore and I would like to use Pure JavaScript this is what I have. The issue is that some elements don't exist yet so when this runs, it doesn't add the eventListener to the selectors.

JS:

```
var keyPressElements = document.querySelectorAll('form[id="4840400"],#waste-form input,#address,#aria-main-search-form-field,#footer-search-field,#aria-feedback-form-field');
keyPressElements.forEach(function(elem) {
    elem.addEventListener('keypress', function() {
        updateLastTypedTime();        
    });
});
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: You can use an [event argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#The_event_listener_callback)’s [`target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) and see if it [`matches`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches) with a selector.

Comment: @dalelandry I don’t see how async functions are relevant here…